# How may I this refactor (improve my code to kame the same functions) and how can I fix the problem with decimals?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am using two console log and I am getting two differents answers inside the same function. What is happening? I want to fix the decimals problems. What would you suggest to improve this code.

I am using two console log and I am getting two differents answers inside the same function. What is happening? I want to fix the decimals problems. What would you suggest to improve this code.

```
function checkCashRegister(price, cash, cid) {
  let change  = Number(Number.parseFloat(cash - price).toFixed(2)) ;
   
  let changeForCustomer = 0 ;
  let billsAndCoinsForCustomer  = []  ;
 
  let sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer = []  ;


  
  let oneHundred  = 0 ;
  let twenty  = 0 ;
  let ten = 0 ;
  let five  = 0 ;
  let one = 0 ;
  let quarter = 0 ;
  let dime  = 0 ;
  let nickel  = 0 ;
  let penny = 0 ;
  let currency  = 
  [
    ["ONE HUNDRED", 100],
    ["TWENTY", 20],
    ["TEN", 10, ],
    ["FIVE", 5],
    ["ONE", 1],
    ["QUARTER", 0.25],
    ["DIME", 0.10],
    ["NICKEL", 0.05],
    ["PENNY", 0.01]
  ]
  let cidCurrency  = []  ;
  let avalaibleCurrency  = []  ;
  for ( let i = 0 ; i < currency.length ; i++ ) {
    for ( let j = 0 ; j <  cid.length ; j++ ) {
        if  ( currency[i][0]  ==  cid[j][0] ){
            cidCurrency.push( cid[j] )  ;
            avalaibleCurrency.push( currency[i] ) ;

        }
    }  
  }
  console.log(  change  )

  for ( let i = 0 ; i < avalaibleCurrency.length ;  i++ )  {

      if  ( change  > avalaibleCurrency[i][1] )  {
          while ( avalaibleCurrency[i][1] <= change  )  {
              change  -=  avalaibleCurrency[i][1]  ;
              changeForCustomer += avalaibleCurrency[i][1]  ;
              billsAndCoinsForCustomer.push(  avalaibleCurrency[i] ); 

        }
      }
  }


  

  for ( let i=0 ; i < billsAndCoinsForCustomer.length ; i++ ) {
      if  ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "ONE HUNDRED" )  {
          oneHundred  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "TWENTY" ){
          twenty  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "TEN" ){
          ten  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "FIVE" ){
          five  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "ONE" ){
          one  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "QUARTER" ){
          quarter  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "DIME" ){
          dime  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else if ( billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][0]  ==  "NICKEL" ){
          niquel  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } else  {
        penny  +=   billsAndCoinsForCustomer[i][1] ;
      } 
   }
        
       if  (   oneHundred > 0 )  {
        sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( [ "ONE HUNDRED", oneHundred ] ) ;
        } 
        if ( twenty  > 0 )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["TWENTY", twenty] )  ; 
        }  
        if ( ten  > 0 )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["TEN", ten] ) ;
        }  
        if ( five  > 0  )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["FIVE", five] )  ;
        } 
         if ( one  > 0  )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["ONE", one ])  ;
        } 
        if ( quarter  > 0  )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["QUARTER" ,quarter  ] )  ;
        } 
         if ( dime  > 0  )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["DIME" , dime] )  ;
        } 
          if ( nickel  > 0  )  {
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["NICKEl", nickel  ] )  ;
        } 
          if (  penny  > 0){
          sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer.push( ["PENNY", penny] )  ;
        }
    //}

 // console.log(  change  , changeForCustomer, billsAndCoinsForCustomer  )
  //console.log(twenty,penny) ;

console.log(change)
  //console.log( sumOfbillsAndCoinsForCustomer)
}
checkCashRegister(0.01, 100, [["PENNY", 1.01], ["NICKEL", 2.05], ["DIME", 3.1], ["QUARTER", 4.25], ["ONE", 90], ["FIVE", 55], ["TEN", 20], ["TWENTY", 60], ["ONE HUNDRED", 100]]);
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: https://www.freecodecamp.org/learn/javascript-algorithms-and-data-structures/intermediate-algorithm-scripting/smallest-common-multiple

Comment: while loop causes infinite loop because value vof 'a.length' never becomes 0 just by increasing counter